# Cannot run in framebuffer mode. error help

Tags: xorg, kde, framebuffer, parrotsec

I'm using ParrotSec and the system I normally used gave an error last night and I could not solve it.

I start normally, then wait, but the KDE does not start and the screen remains black. I pressed the <kbd>Alt+F6</kbd> keys, I wrote `startx` after logging. And gave an error

```
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIds for all framebuffer devices
```